# unknown module 'rsync_sst-undo_dir' error when syncing node

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, galera

I have a galera cluster with 3 nodes in QA environement.. There was a abrupt shut down of the nodes and I restarted and bootstrapped the first nodewhich is working fine. The second node when I try to start gives the error , "rsyncd[30958]: unknown module 'rsync_sst-undo_dir' tried from  XXX" .

In mysql log :
 `[Warning] WSREP: 0.0 : State transfer to 1.0 (x) failed: -255 (Unknown error 255) [ERROR] WSREP: /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():1207: Will never receive state. Need to abort.`

Not sure what causes this error,

`rsyncd[30958]: unknown module 'rsync_sst-undo_dir' tried from XXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT unknown module 'rsync_sst-undo_dir' "`

Any pointers would be very helpful .

Thanks

Any pointers would be very helpful .

Comment: Which version(s) (ws_rep_patch_version)?

Answer (score 0):

I got that on 10.6.11 servers trying to connect to 10.6.12 clusters. After updating to 10.6.12 everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried as @Allan said
Update for all nodes have the same version and everything works perfectly.

For example, I update from 10.4.26 to 10.4.28.
Do not need to uninstall the old version, your config will stay on your server. Changing to the version you need (mariadb-10.4.28 is mine)

```
cd /tmp 

wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
    
chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup

./mariadb_repo_setup --mariadb-server-version="mariadb-10.4.28" 

sudo yum install mariadb-server mariadb-backup
```

or

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-backup
```

after installing mariadb will auto start, Take care if you don't have a primary node (you should start the primary node first and install the version following to your primary node)